# Laravel : How to divide a file into multiple files?

Tags: php, laravel

How to divide a file into multiple files with laravel or php?

For example:

There is a file `demo.blade.php`:

```
<div class="card-block">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-1">fruits</div>
        <div class="col-11">
            apple,pear,peach
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="card-block">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-1">aminals</div>
        <div class="col-11">
            cat,dog,calf
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="card-block">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-1">vehicles</div>
        <div class="col-11">
            car,bus,motorbike
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to write some code to divide the `demo.blade.php` into three files:

`fruits.blade.php`
`aminals.blade.php`
`vehicles.blade.php`

The content is each `<div class="card-block"></div>`.

How to do it?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use Blade template extending methods. see docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#extending-blade

Comment: What is the reason ? And who is making the one file ?

Comment: you mean diffrent blade.php files thorugh code? why?
Or do you want to know how you can `@extend` a layout?

Answer (score 0):

You can use other blade in your blade file like this :

```
@include('fruits.blade.php')
@include('aminals.blade.php')
@include('vehicles.blade.php')
```

But this is not a good idea. Instead you can make a template like this :

```
<div class="card-block">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-1">{{ $title }}</div>
        <div class="col-11">
            {{ $content }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And use it everywhere :

```
@include('template', ['title' => 'foo', 'content' => 'bar'])
```

Anyway I don't know your purpose of doing this. And you can explain more to give you more examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [Blade Components](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#components-and-slots)

```
//This is the template cardblock.blade.php
<div class="card-block">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-1">{{ $title }}</div>
        <div class="col-11">
            {{ $slot }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And you can use it like this

```
@component('cardblock')
    @slot('title')
        fruits
    @endslot

    apple,pear,peach
@endcomponent

@component('cardblock')
    @slot('title')
        aminals
    @endslot

    cat,dog,calf
@endcomponent

@component('cardblock')
    @slot('title')
        vehicles
    @endslot

    car,bus,motorbike
@endcomponent
```